# How to customize Spree checkout process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

My environment.

```
Mac OSX 10.7.4
Ruby 1.9.3p0
Rails 3.2.3
Spree 1.1.0
```

Hello, I am Japanese programmer and newbie to Spree. I would like to customize Spree's checkout process to remove checkout steps such as selecting delivery method and payment method.

According to the [Spree Guides](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/checkout.html), I need to define an entirely new state machine for `Order` model.

So, I added `order_decorator.rb` to `app/models` directory as shown in the following.

```
# app/models/order_decorator.rb

module SpreeCustomExtension
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    def self.activate
      Order.class_eval do
        Order.state_machines[:state] = StateMachine::Machine.new(Order, :initial => 'cart') do
          after_transition :to => 'complete', :do => :complete_order
          before_transition :to => 'complete', :do => :process_payment

          event :next do
            transition :from => 'cart', :to => 'payment'
            transition :from => 'payment', :to => 'confirm'
            transition :from => 'confirm', :to => 'complete'
          end

          event :cancel do
            transition :to => 'canceled', :if => :allow_cancel?
          end
          event :return do
            transition :to => 'returned', :from => 'awaiting_return'
          end
          event :resume do
            transition :to => 'resumed', :from => 'canceled', :if => :allow_resume?
          end
          event :authorize_return do
            transition :to => 'awaiting_return'
          end

          before_transition :to => 'complete' do |order|
            begin
              order.process_payments!
            rescue Spree::GatewayError
              if Spree::Config[:allow_checkout_on_gateway_error]
                true
              else
                false
              end
            end
          end

          after_transition :to => 'complete', :do => :finalize!
          after_transition :to => 'confirm', :do => :create_tax_charge!
          after_transition :to => 'payment', :do => :create_shipment!
          after_transition :to => 'canceled', :do => :after_cancel

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I added `spree_site.rb` file to my `lib/` directory.

```
# lib/spree_site.rb

module SpreeSite
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    def self.activate
      Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../app/**/*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
        Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
      end
    end

    def load_tasks
    end

    config.to_prepare &method(:activate).to_proc
  end
end
```

But, It seems that there is no change at all. Anyone know where I should modify to customize checkout process?

please suggest some good spree tutorial or advice. I really appreciate any advices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be within the Spree namespace, overriding Spree::Order and not simply Order.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try within Spree's namespace. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think your order decorator should look a little different. 
Just make a file `app/models/spree/order_decorator.rb`

And start it something like this

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  state_machine do
    before_transition to: "address" do |order|
    ...
  end
end
```